# Access denied in python call

Tags: python, svn, call

I'm trying to do a SVN ignore through a Python script.

I am trying to run a command like:

```
call(['"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe" propset svn:ignore "C:\dir\file.dcu" "C:\dir"'])
```

Here's the Python error message that I get:

[image: error]

It's saying that I don't have access to do this. However, when I try to run this command in a CMD.EXE shell, everything works fine.

---

**EDIT**

Maybe this is a clue, perhaps I can't escape characters like this

[image: quotes]

Comment: I seem to be having more success with os.system
os.system(r'"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe" propset svn:ignore "C:\dir\file.dcu" "C:\dir"')

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not handling escape sequences properly.  `\b` denotes a backspace character and `\f` denotes a formfeed:

```
>>> '\b'
'\x08'
>>> '\f'
'\x0c'
>>>
```

This makes your paths invalid.  To fix the problem, simply use a [raw-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals):

```
call([r'"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe" propset svn:ignore "C:\dir\file.dcu" "C:\dir"'])
```

By prefixing the string literal with `r`, we tell Python to not interpret escape sequences.

Comment: Thanks, great idea, unfortunately this hasn't made a difference